# Describe the transformation of $F(x)=x^2$ represented by $G(x)=(x+4)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

I am completely confused in my math class and I was wondering if someone could help me on this question by explaining it to me step by step?

The question looks like this.

> Describe the transformation of $F(x)=x^2$ represented by $G$.

1. $G(x)=(x+4)^2$

Comment: The class is Advance algebra and the question comes from the text book. The text book is called 'Big Ideas Math Algebra 2' The question comes from Chapter 2 review 2.1. I hope that helped a bit.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will look there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks that what you need is $F(x)=G(x-4)$, i.e. $F$ is described in terms of $G$

Comment: To me, it looks like we are supposed to express $G(x) = (x + 4)^2$ as a transformation of $F(x) = x^2$, that is, express $G$ in terms of $F$.

Answer (score -1):

When describing a transformation, I think of that parabola's vertex in f and in g. I believe that it is shifted 4 units to the left.

(x+4) = 0
x = -4